# Difference between two XML parsers in pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have two lightweight XML parsers (see below). One (1) is more efficient but the results interact oddly with pandas. The other is slow but doesn't cause unusual errors. The problem is, I can't find where the two would actually produce anything different.

1)

```
keep=[]
for en,a in enumerate(open(inputfile,'r')):
    if not a.startswith("<Record"):continue
    line=a.strip().split("'")
    line[0]=line[0].replace("<Record ",'')
    line.pop() # deletes the final "/>"
    store={}
    for x in range(0, len(line), 2):
        if not line[x]:continue
        line[x] = line[x].strip().rstrip("=")
        print(line[x])
        print(line[x+1])
        store[line[x]]=line[x+1]
        if line[x] == "id17":
            id17s.append(line[x+1])
    keep.append(store)
doc = pandas.DataFrame(keep,index=id17s) # contains all XML records.
```

2)

```
keep=[]
for en,a in enumerate(open(inputfile,'r')):
    if not a.startswith("<Record"):continue
    line=a.strip().split("' ")
    line[0]=line[0].replace("<Record ",'')
    line.pop()
    store={}
    for x in range(len(line)):
        if not line[x]:continue
        try:
            trait,evalx=line[x].replace("'",'').strip().split('=',1)
        except:
            print line
            print line[x].replace("'",'').strip().split('=')
            sys.exit()
        store[trait]=evalx
        if trait == "id17":
            id17s.append(evalx)
    keep.append(store)
doc = pandas.DataFrame(keep,index=id17s) # contains all XML records.
```

Both parsers are followed with

```
doc_df = doc.apply(pandas.to_numeric, args=('ignore',))  # set missing values to nan
header=list(doc_df.columns.values) #Get columns names (header)
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or do you expect us to look at this unreadable code and tell you what it does without any means whatsoever to run it?

Comment: Well i think one of the biggest things is that your loop in the first parser is only doing even lines, while your second parser checks every line. Its hard to guess without being able to profile what else is causing issues.